# Unable to format my pendrive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, disk, disk-management, disk-utility

I want to try to format my pendrive but it show the error as

> Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type /dev/sdc1        2048 7802879 7800832  3.7G 83 Linux
>
> Command (m for help): w The partition table has been altered. Calling
>   ioctl() to re-read partition table. Re-reading the partition table
>   failed.: Device or resource busy
>
> The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the
>   next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8).

when i try it from GUI

[image: Error formating volume]

The size of pendrive is 4 GB but when i see it in file browser it shows the size 69 GB, why?

[image]

How can i format this pendrive in Fat or NTFS format?

Answer (score 1):

Your pendrive have an error, so we have to fix that first!

Open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to find out your pendrives name. Then:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=16
```

where the x is the letter of your pendrive! 
Type in your password and hit enter!  This fixes the wrong header entry on the pendrive, by overwriting any and all with zerroes, in the first 8 KB!

After that you can use your normal partition program: Set to Dos and make NTFS or Fat32 partition for compatibility with other computers and multimedia equipment!

I found this on our site here: [Fixing bad USBstick](http://goo.gl/nWXA61)