# How do I format a stubborn usb pendrive?

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, usb-drive, persistence

Long story short I have a microsd card which was used as an installer for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and somehow stopped working for anything else but "viewing"
It has a 6GB persistent volume (casper-rw) which I think is the cause of all evil, even though I didn't have much problems with persistant usb drives in the past

[image: gparted]

[image: diskmgmt]

[image: device properties]

**wth is LUN 0 anyway?**

[image: minitool part wiz]

### What I tried so far:

- 3 different sd readers
- Formatting in Windows using standard-ish tools (diskpart/diskmgmt, and a few 3rd party like minitool partition wiz & sd card formatter by tuxera)
- Formatting in multiple Linux distros using mke2fs & gparted
- Zeroing using either Windows tools mentioned before, gparted and dd
- [I can't format my live-USB pendrive (udisks-error-quark, 11)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832914/i-cant-format-my-live-usb-pendrive-udisks-error-quark-11)
- [Unable to format my pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847399/unable-to-format-my-pendrive)

---

Any time I try to make any changes using Windows built-in tools it says it fails, while Minitool, mkfs, gparted & dd all claim success and reload, they still show the same partitions.

Would very much appreciate ANY help getting it back in working order

Comment: Stop flailing. Doing several Windows & Linux "things" to the USB, then asking "what's wrong?" is silly. Use `sudo lsblk -f` to see the partitions. `sudo umount` each partition of the USB. Then, read `man parted gparted` and use `gparted` to repair the disk.

Comment: @waltinator No mount points. And I was just trying my luck getting it to format in any way I'm familiar with

Comment: You can analyze your problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and, I hope, find a solution. Good luck :-)

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the exhaustive guide!
The drive is recognized and I also believe (key word haha) it isn't read-only. I've tried everything laid out there, no-go. At least I learned a little on the way :)
Currently trying to nuke it totally using mkusb-dus, if that doesn't work I'll try the dd command from the answer below yours

Comment: ^Still not working.
trying to dd the whole drive again but now using bs=1, i don't really know if it will make a difference though

Comment: bs=1 will make it ridiculously slow, and maybe also cause excessive wear. I recommend bs=4096.

Comment: If still no luck, I'm afraid that your pendrive is damaged beyond repair, maybe 'gridlocked'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Open applications -> type Disks and click on it to open,the program open with graphical interface with displaying all disks, select the erasing disk, under that use - sign to erase.

[image]

Comment: That's a part of what I already tried, but I did it again just to be sure. For a second the app "flashes" as if the disk just completed deleting successfully and then just goes back to how it was

Comment: John if you try to use the -  sign it will delete only the selected partition.instead that go to top of menu to right you can see three stars just place the mouse on it you will show the further option,in that choose format disk option. I think this will work.